# Powershell group array collection by path as one element, then remaining items into array as second element

Tags: arrays, hashtable, distinct, powershell-5.1

Long story short, I'm pumping NTFS permissions into accesscontroldsc/ntfsentry (was using cntfs, but it doesn't work with winsrv2019 and has different keys) dynamically from a source server using get-acl.  get-acl writes out below right now, but I want the path as a distinct element or key, then all the rest (identityreference, fsr,...) as the value or nested array in a collection of hashes or arrays.  If this is easier to do in the get-acl call, I'm using below to pull the output seen under and would love any help.

```
Get-Acl "E:\DenClass" | Select -ExpandProperty Access | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.IdentityReference -like "$env:userdomain*" -or $_.IdentityReference -like "*IIS_IUSRS*"} | sort | get-unique
```

Path                           E:\Path1
FileSystemRights               Modify, Synchronize
IdentityReference              domain\account1
Inherit                        This Folder Subfolders And Files
AccessControlType              Allow

Path                           E:\Path1
FileSystemRights               Modify, Synchronize
IdentityReference              domain\account2
Inherit                        This Folder Subfolders And Files
AccessControlType              Allow

Path                           E:\Path2
FileSystemRights               Modify, Synchronize
IdentityReference              domain\account1
Inherit                        This Folder Subfolders And Files
AccessControlType              Allow

Path                           E:\Path2
FileSystemRights               Modify, Synchronize
IdentityReference              domain\account2
Inherit                        This Folder Subfolders And Files

Desired output (if an array)

```
$ary=@(
@("E:\Path1",@(@("domain\account1",'Allow',@('Modify, Synchronize'),'This folder subfolders and files','Present'),@("domain\account2",$true, 'Allow','FullControl','This folder subfolders and files'))),
@("E:\Path2",@(@("Builtin\Administrators",$true,'Allow',@('Modify, Synchronize'),'This folder subfolders and files','Present'),@("BUILTIN\Users", 'Allow',@('Modify, Synchronize'),'This folder subfolders and files')))
)
```

or if hash, something like:

```
$hash=@{
"E:\Path1"=@("domain\account1",'Allow',@('Modify, Synchronize'),'This folder subfolders and files','Present'),@("domain\account2", 'Allow','FullControl','This folder subfolders and files')
"E:\Path2"=@("domain\account1",'Allow',@('Modify, Synchronize'),'This folder subfolders and files','Present'),@("domain\account2", 'Allow',@('Modify, Synchronize'),'This folder subfolders and files')
}
```

Conceptually something like below if using get-acl, but what I have doesn't work at all

```
[hashtable]$hash =@{}
(Get-Acl "E:\DenClass").foreach({
$key= $_.Path
$ary1=@()
foreach ($i in $_.access)
{
$ary1+=,@($_.access.IdentityReference,@($_.access.FileSystemRights),$_.access.AccessControlType,$_.access.Inherit)
}
$value = $ary1
$hash.add($key,$value)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll need to circle back and edit this answer (clean up), but in case I don't, there is enough content to do what was requested and it offers both array and hash responses.  The path is piped into get-acl from another function, so that will be the source that's prefixed into the array.

```
function  ConvertTo-Hashtable {
    <#
    .Synopsis
        Converts an object to a hashtable
    .DESCRIPTION
        PowerShell v4 seems to have trouble casting some objects to Hashtable.
        This function is a workaround to convert PS Objects to [Hashtable]
    .LINK
        https://github.com/alainQtec/.files/blob/main/src/scripts/Converters/ConvertTo-Hashtable.ps1
    .NOTES
        Base ref: https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/turning-objects-into-hash-tables-2
    #>
    PARAM(
        # The object to convert to a hashtable
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true)]
        $InputObject,

        # Forces the values to be strings and converts them by running them through Out-String
        [switch]$AsString,

        # If set, empty properties are Included
        [switch]$AllowNulls,

        # Make each hashtable to have it's own set of properties, otherwise,
        # (default) each InputObject is normalized to the properties on the first object in the pipeline
        [switch]$DontNormalize
    )
    BEGIN {
        $headers = @()
    }
    PROCESS {
        if (!$headers -or $DontNormalize) {
            $headers = $InputObject | Get-Member -type Properties | Select-Object -expand name
        }
        $OutputHash = @{}
        if ($AsString) {
            foreach ($col in $headers) {
                if ($AllowNulls -or ($InputObject.$col -is [bool] -or ($InputObject.$col))) {
                    $OutputHash.$col = $InputObject.$col | Out-String -Width 9999 | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($col in $headers) {
                if ($AllowNulls -or ($InputObject.$col -is [bool] -or ($InputObject.$col))) {
                    $OutputHash.$col = $InputObject.$col
                }
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        return $OutputHash
    }
}

$path="C:\temp"
$kperms= Get-Acl $path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access  |
  Select-Object @{N="identityreference";E={$_.identityreference}}, 
    @{n="filesystemrights";e={ $_.filesystemrights }},
    @{n="AccessControlType";e={ $_.AccessControlType }},
    @{n="Inherit";e={ $_.Inherit }}

#Produces a hash table of what you wanted, but it's transposed think you can use this 
$kpermsHash = ConvertTo-Hashtable $kperms -AllowNulls -DontNormalize

#if you can't use the orignal output i went thru and transposed it into an array.
$TransposedHash = @()
$max = $kpermsHash.AccessControlType.Count
for($i=0; $i -lt $max; $i++)
{
    $TransposedHash += ,@($kpermsHash.identityreference[$i],$kpermsHash.filesystemrights[$i],$kpermsHash.AccessControlType[$i],$kpermsHash.Inherit[$i])
    #Write-Host "$($kpermsHash.identityreference[$i])     $($kpermsHash.filesystemrights[$i])     $($kpermsHash.AccessControlType[$i])      '$($kpermsHash.Inherit[$i])'"
    
}
$ary += @($path,$TransposedHash)
write-host  $ary


Write-Host "testlast"
```